# Is there a builtin service to get the time (and timezone) from a windows 2008 server?

Tags: c#, timezone

I am creating a .NET service that gets timestamp information (in the local server time zone) from another Windows 2008 server. I don't have control over the other server, and I need a way to programatically get the timezone offset from that server so that I can interpret the timestamp information as a time in UTC.  Is there a builtin service to get the time (and timezone) from a windows 2008 server?  Thanks.

Comment: From an app running on the server? What's wrong with `DateTime.UtcNow`? Or using `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`?

Comment: Can you not change the server to give the timestamp in UTC to start with?

Comment: @JonSkeet We have NO control over the server that we are getting the information from, but we do know the timestamp info is in local time.

Comment: @DaveZych My service is running on a sever that I control.  I am getting timestamp information from a server that I do not control.

Comment: Whoever down-voted my question, please provide a reason why or some constructive criticism.

Comment: The time offset is a known variable.  Why don't you just determine what the offset is and use that?  As for the downvote the question does not have enough information.  The solution should be pretty simple, the local time information is known, and you can adjust.

Comment: @Ramhound The server that my software is running on is a separate server from the one that I am getting timestamp info from. I don't know how to say that more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/03/28/use-powershell-to-see-time-zone-information-on-remote-computers.aspx

It discusses using powershell, you may need to have access to the server, but perhaps it will help if your looking for a way to access programatically.

If you are able to map to the server, you could also try:

```
net time \\SERVER_NAME
```